# *ngFor and http request in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, request, rendering, ngfor

I've a the seguent list-componet

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-vote-list',
    template: `<my-vote *ngFor="let question of questions" [question]="question"></my-vote>`
})
export class VoteListComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private voteService: VoteService, private authService: AuthService){}

    private votes: any[];

    ngOnInit(){
        this.voteService.keepVotation()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.votes = data;
                console.log(this.votes);
            }, 
            err => console.log(err)
        );
    }
}
```

When i retrieve data from my service:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import "rxjs/Rx";

import { Vote } from '../insert-vote/vote';

@Injectable()
export class VoteService {

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    public votations: any[];

    keepVotation(){
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token') : '';
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/vote/votations/' + token)
            .map(response =>{
                const data = response.json().obj;
                let votations: any[] = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let votation = new Vote(data[i].title, data[i].promoter, data[i].theme, data[i].file, null, data[i]._id);
                    votations.push(votation);
                };
                this.votations = votations;
                return votations;
            })
    }
}
```

it doesn't bind data to this.vote that result undefined. I Make the same thing in another component and every thing works.
It's the first view that i load
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: In the *ngFor you are talking about `questions` but in the class you define `votes`..

Comment: can you show your my-vote component ?

Comment: @PierreDuc you are right but i have try to change the variable's name, with votes in the *ngFor it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Ashu import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { Vote } from '../insert-vote/vote';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-vote',
  templateUrl: './templates/vote.component.html'
})

export class VoteComponent implements OnInit{
 @Input() question: Vote;

 ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.question)
 }

 public h: boolean = false;

 public radioModel:string = 'no';

 public oneAtATime:boolean = true;

 onSubmit(form: NgForm){
  console.log(form.value);
 }
  
}

Comment: what you are getting in console.log(this.votes);

Comment: @Ashu exactly what I expect: [Vote, Vote], I don't understand why Angular doesn't bind it